# How to validate xml response in jmeter using wsdl similar like soapui

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I'm using soap service to test in jmeter and xml schema validation is failing with "error: line=2 col=446 s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'definitions' must be from the schema namespace, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'." this error.

I gave wsdl path for XML Schema assertion input similar like SOAPUI.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use JMeter's [XML Schema Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XML_Schema_Assertion) you need to convert WSDL to [XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp).

It can be done, i.e. using [QTAssistant](https://www.paschidev.com/downloads.aspx) application:

[image]

[image]

Once you get the XSD you will be able to use it with the XML Schema Assertion.

More information: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps/)

Comment: thanks for the response @Dmitri T, got to know that this tool is licensed one, is there any other opensource tool do this action?